# C: Storing up to a million entries in a hash table

Tags: c, optimization, performance, hashmap, hashtable

I'm working on a project where efficiency is crucial. A hash table would be very helpful since I need to easily look up the memory address of a node based on a key. The only problem I foresee is this hash table will need to handle up to 1 million entries. As I understand it usually hash tables buckets are a linked list so that they can handle multiple entries in the same bucket. It seems to me that with a million entries these lists would be way too slow. What is the common way of implementing something like this. Maybe swapping a standard linked list out for a skip list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a hash table with a million entries, normally you'd have at least 2 million buckets. I don't remember all the statistics (the key term is "birthday paradox"), but the vast majority of the buckets will have zero or one items. You can, in principle, be *very* unlucky and get all items in one bucket - but you'd have to be even more unlucky than those people who seem to get struck by lightning every other day.

For hashtables that grow, the normal trick is to grow by a constant percentage - the usual textbook case being growth by doubling the hash-table size. You do this whenever the number of items in the hashtable reaches a certain proportion of the hashtable size, irrespective of how many buckets are actually being used. This gives **amortized expected** performance of O(1) for inserts, deletes and searches.

The linked list in each bucket of a hash-table is just a way of handling collisions - improbable in a per-operation sense, but over the life of a significant hash table, they *do* happen - especially as the hash-table gets more than half full.

Linked lists aren't the only way to handle collisions - there's a huge amount of lore about this topic. Walter Bright (developer of the D programming language) has advocated using binary trees rather than linked lists, claiming that his Dscript gained a significant performance boost relative to Javascript from this design choice.

He used simple (unbalanced) binary trees when I asked, so the worst-case performance was the same as for linked lists, but the key point I guess is that the binary tree handling code is simple, and the hash table itself makes the odds of building large unbalanced trees very small.

In principle, you could just as easily use treaps, red-black trees or AVL trees. An interesting option may be to use splay trees for collision handling. But overall, this is a minor issue for a few library designers and a few true obsessives to worry about.

Comment: Yet another way to handle collisions is cuckoo hashing.

Comment: The theory of that seems to dismiss the possibility of one pair of keys colliding for both hashes, or of both possibile locations for one key being unavailable due to collisions. Probably means I haven't looked into it enough. I've seen double-hash schemes before, but not heard the term "cuckoo hashing" before reading your comment about five minutes ago, so I could very easily be missing a specific trick or two.

Comment: @Steve314 Well that is easily handled recursively (replace the object again at its position and repeat) which I assume you're aware ;) I agree that I don't see what magic tricks they're using to assure a constant lookup (at least not how those tricks wouldn't work for a linked hashmap as well)

Answer (score 3):

You lose all the advantages of a hash table if the per-bucket lists ever have more than a few entries.  The usual way to make a hash table scale to millions of entries is to make the primary hash array resizable, so even with millions of entries, the bucket lists stay short.

Comment: I'd have to imagine resizing a hash table is a pretty expensive operation. Is there any better way than iterate through every entry?

Comment: @blcArmadillo: you don't have to resize it, its size should be decided at creation time.

Comment: @blcArmadillo - in an amortized sense, if you resize the table by e.g. doubling, it's very cheap. Resizing the table is O(n), but you do it rarely. Basically, for each insert, you "charge" an extra unit credit to pay towards the resize - each operation only gets charged a constant amount, and the resize (when it occurs) is paid for from "saved time".

Comment: @ruslik - that isn't very practical in the real world. You normally don't know how many items you will need to insert before you start. All the main hashtable implementations in standard libraries that I know of (Python, Java, C#, C++0x, Javascript, ...) grow/shrink their hashtables depending on the numbers of items inserted.

Comment: @Steve314: You're right, it makes sense, especially for generic libraries.

Comment: @blcArmadillo: It's possible to avoid moving the existing entries if you remember the previous sizes, and look in several places for the key when you do a key lookup.  You can also create the larger table alongside the smaller one, and progressively move the entries over as they're looked up.  There's lots of tricks...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Tree instead of a List in the individual "buckets". (AVL or similar)

EDIT: well, Skip List would do too. (and seems to be faster) - O(log n) is what you aim for.

Comment: Strictly, the hashtable already gives you O(1) expected. If you're looking for an asymptotic improvement, you need a guaranteed balanced tree for collision handling - something with worst-case O(log n), to give the hashtable itself amortized worst-case O(log n) operations rather than amortized worst-case O(n). Because a skip list is randomized, it won't give that guarantee - though it'll probably give a performance boost in practice.

Comment: O(log n) for the structure in one bucket for collision handling.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of entries does not matter, only the average number of entries per bucket (N / size of hash). Use a hash function with larger domain (for example, 20 bits, or even larger) to ensure that.

Of course, this will take up more memory, but that's it, it's a common memory vs speed tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you or not, but maybe: http://memcached.org/

Comment: Something about that image... it's going to give me nightmares.

Answer (score 0):

If your keys have normal distribution (That's a very big IF), then the expected number of insertions into the hashtable to exhaust all the buckets in the hashtable is M*logM  ( Natural log, to the base e), where M is the number of buckets.

Was surprised couldn't find this easily online!

I have posted the derivation of the same on [my blog](https://appolo85.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/some-fun-with-hash-table-performance-analysis/),and verified it  with Code, using rand().It does seem to be a pretty good estimate.